# How to use visitor for an AST in java

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using [org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fpackage-summary.html) to generate an AST of some given Java source code.
After generating the AST I have the root node.

How can I use an `ASTVisitor` so that I can parse my AST to get all the leaf nodes?

Comment: What about this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html

Answer (score 4):

### Visitor Pattern

I suggest you begin by doing some reading on the [Visitor Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) if you are not already familiar with that particular design pattern.

Essentially, it boils down to using double dispatch to invoke the appropriate method on a `Visitor` class, passing the visited object as a parameter.  Generally, it is implemented in a similar fashion to the following (YMMV):

```
public interface Node {
    void acceptVisitor(Visitor v);

    Collection<Node> getChildren();
}

// Incomplete implementation, for demonstration only
public class SubNode implements Node {

    @Override
    public void acceptVisitor(Visitor v) {
        if(v.preVisit(this)) {
            v.visit(this);
            v.postVisit(this);
        }
        getChildren().forEach(child -> child.accept(v));
    }
}

public interface Visitor {
    boolean preVisit(Node node);

    void visit(Node node);

    void visit(SubNode node);

    void postVisit(Node node);
}
```

The `Visitor` interface is then implemented, and passed into the `acceptVisitor` method of a `Node` (often, but not always, the root node of the tree).

---

### Eclipse Implementation

**For a more thorough overview of how to implement your `ASTVisitor`, you might check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)**

In your particular case, you need to extend the [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html) class, overriding the `visit` method for the [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.html) implementations you care about.  Then pass an instance of this `ASTVisitor` into the [`accept`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fpackage-summary.html) method of the root node of your AST.

---

### Leaf Nodes

Since you're looking for leaf nodes (which are defined as AST nodes having no children), you can do something like [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853270/2489497) to retrieve the children of an `ASTNode`:

```
public Object[] getChildren(ASTNode node) {
    List list= node.structuralPropertiesForType();
    for (int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        StructuralPropertyDescriptor curr= (StructuralPropertyDescriptor) list.get(i);
            Object child= node.getStructuralProperty(curr);
        if (child instanceof List) {
                return ((List) child).toArray();
        } else if (child instanceof ASTNode) {
            return new Object[] { child };
            }
        return new Object[0];
    }
}
```

By calling this method and passing each node you examine, you can determine whether the node has no children (the `length` of the returned array will be 0) and add those to a `Collection` in your `ASTVisitor` to keep track of them.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a correct way, but this works to get all the leaf nodes.

1) Maintain two sets of Nodes, let's say `S1` and `S2`.
2) Traverse all the nodes and add every node to `S1`.
3) If `node.getParent() != null`, then add `node.getParent()` to `S2`
4) This means `S1` keeps track of all the nodes whereas `S2` has all the internal nodes. So leaf nodes are `S1 - S2`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An example is this:

```
package de.vogella.jdt.astsimple.handler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;

public class MethodVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
  List<MethodDeclaration> methods = new ArrayList<MethodDeclaration>();
    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
      methods.add(node);
      return super.visit(node);
    }

    public List<MethodDeclaration> getMethods() {
      return methods;
    }
}
```