# figure out which token belongs to which AST node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I encounter this problem while implementing a parsering project.
I use Eclipse JDT to do the parsing, and what I got is a parsed abstract syntax tree.

I also need to token information, like which token belongs to which AST node. Due to JDT doesn't provide me direct information and I'll need to port the same concept to C family codes, I prefer using an algorithm way to solve it.

The problem could be described more algorithm-wise.

For each AST node, it has a starting offset and an ending offset in source code. Due to AST property, the region of each node won't cross the boundary. (Won't have an expression 1->20 and another statement from 4->23, but having a node 1->20 and another node 1->20 is possible)

Each token also has starting offset and length. The non corssing boundary property still hold.
 And each token won't overlap other tokens.

I have a AST and a list of tokens in hand, and I want to match each token to a AST node, to the AST node having narrowest region but still contain whole token. Due to the non-crossing property, we could only check the starting offset of each token, and find the AST node having narrowest region.

For example, if I have a statement `int a = (3 * (5 + b));`, the token stream is `int`, `a`, `=`, `(`, `3`, `*`, `(`, `5`, `+`, `b`, `)`, `)`, `;` AST may look like

```
statement
  |
assignment
  |    | 
id    expression 1
       |
      binary operation
       |        |
       int      expression 2
                 |
               binary operation
                 |       | 
                int       id
```

then I want `int`, `;` belongs to statement, `b`, inner `(`, `)` belong to second expression.

Although I have an AST in hand, use it to look up particular AST node would require me to write methods for all kinds of ast node of java language, since there is no common way to visit their children nodes. Therefore I'm looking for a general algorithm solution.

Comment: Can you give more details on your claim "there is no common way to visit their children nodes" and its relation with "I'm looking for a general algorithm solution"?

Comment: "There is no common way to visit their children" means each node has different number of children. A block may have many statements. A binary operation will have two children. And JDT's AST don't have `getChildren()` kind of methods to let me visit each children of current AST node.

Comment: Probably you can use this to get the children? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841789/children-of-org-eclipse-jdt-core-dom-astnode

Comment: My "general algorithm solution" means using node starting offset, ending offset and token starting offset to solve this problem. Not depending on functions which JDT AST may provide to solve that.

Comment: Because I'll need to write the same thing for C family source code, so I prefer solve this by algorithm. But thank you @justhalf, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that I could use visitor to solve this problem as well. Let the visitor to visit AST and remember the last seen AST node enclose the given token. Then that AST node is the tightest AST node containing that token.